# Parse Issue (Xcode): Module 'fluttertoast' not found

Tags: ios, xcode, flutter, android-studio, visual-studio-code

i have flutter code which is used to build ios and android app, when code run in xcode using simulator, it runs fine, but when run in android studio or in visual studio code using

> flutter run --flavor stg

get the following error :

> Parse Issue (Xcode): Module 'fluttertoast' not found
> GeneratedPluginRegistrant.m:131:8 Could not build the application for
> the simulator. Error launching application on iPhone 13.

Please help :(

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Parse Issue (Xcode): Module 'fluttertoast' not found (in target 'Toast' from project 'Pods')](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/72358846/parse-issue-xcode-module-fluttertoast-not-found-in-target-toast-from-pro)

Answer (score 2):

It's lookes likes you are opening incorrect file. you should open
open `runner.xcworkspace` ,it worked!
also run `pod install` in IOS directory.

Comment: sorry bro, in xcode my code run well and can show in simulator, but when i run my code in android studio, code show error Module 'fluttertoast' not found