# Parse Issue (Xcode): Module 'fluttertoast' not found (in target 'Toast' from project 'Pods')

Tags: flutter, dart, flutter-dependencies, flutter-test

```
Parse Issue (Xcode): Module 'fluttertoast' not found
/Users/anand/StudioProjects/untitled/ios/Runner/GeneratedPluginRegistrant.m:11:8

Could not build the application for the simulator.
Error launching application on iPhone 11 Pro.
```

I trapped this error almost 24 hours. Please help somebody, I used the `fluttertoast: ^8.0.9` library maximum places in my project, If I remove the library project runs as usual but if I add the library the above error throws. I don't know how to get rid of the error. I tried most of the answers in the stackoverflow.

```
import 'package:flutter/material.dart';
import 'package:fluttertoast/fluttertoast.dart';

void main() {
  runApp(const MyApp());
}

class MyApp extends StatelessWidget {
  const MyApp({Key? key}) : super(key: key);
  @override
  Widget build(BuildContext context) {
    return MaterialApp(
      title: 'Flutter Demo',
      theme: ThemeData(
        primarySwatch: Colors.blue,
      ),
      home: const MyHomePage(title: 'Flutter Demo Home Page'),
    );
  }
}

class MyHomePage extends StatefulWidget {
  const MyHomePage({Key? key, required this.title}) : super(key: key);

  final String title;

  @override
  State<MyHomePage> createState() => _MyHomePageState();
}

class _MyHomePageState extends State<MyHomePage> {
  
  @override
  Widget build(BuildContext context) {
  
    return Scaffold(
      appBar: AppBar(
        
        title: Text(widget.title),
      ),
      body: Center(
        child: Column(
          mainAxisAlignment: MainAxisAlignment.center,
          children: <Widget>[
            const Text(
              'Hello flutter',
            ),
            
          ],
        ),
      ),
      floatingActionButton: FloatingActionButton(
        onPressed: (){
          Fluttertoast.showToast(
              msg: "This is Center Short Toast",
              toastLength: Toast.LENGTH_SHORT,
              gravity: ToastGravity.CENTER,
              timeInSecForIosWeb: 1,
              backgroundColor: Colors.red,
              textColor: Colors.white,
              fontSize: 16.0
          );
        },
        tooltip: 'Increment',
        child: const Icon(Icons.add),
      ), // This trailing comma makes auto-formatting nicer for build methods.
    );
  }
}
```

Please help me how to get rid of the error.

Comment: have you update IOS (11) version in deployment info version in Xcode and podfile?

Answer (score 15):

Try this one. It worked for me!

```
pod repo update
pod install
```

Comment: tried, not works bro

Answer (score 7):

Try step:

1. Delete the **"podfile"** and **"podfile. Lock"** files in the IOS folder
2. Terminal execution: execute `flutter clean` in IOS file directory“
3. Execute `flutter pub get` in the ". Yaml" file of Android studio“
4. Terminal execution: execute `pod install` in IOS directory“

Comment: thanks for ur answer.bt already tried

Comment: ONLY answer that helped me! I ran these commands in macOS, not within Windows and this worked.

Answer (score 2):

First, try this:

```
1. go into ios folder
2. delete the Podfile.lock file
3. `rm -rf Pods`
4. `pod cache clean --all`
5. `pod deintegrate`
6. `pod setup`
7. `pod install`
8. `pod upgrade`
```

If that doesn't work, try:

```
1. Open the project through VSCode
2. Check `ios > Pods` folder for the `Toast` folder. 
3. If that folder exists, run `flutter build ios` through VSCode
4. If the build succeeds, try running the project on XCode.
```

This worked for me!

Answer (score 0):

try installing cocoapod which is dependency manager for swift and objective c and then running command

```
pod deintegrate
pod install
```

inside iOS folder in the Flutter project .This should be same for what ever flutter plugin we are going to set up in the project.Please check this link as well
[macos-deploy-to-ios-devices](https://flutter.dev/docs/get-started/install/macos#deploy-to-ios-devices)

Comment: already tried bro\

Comment: tried it on android device ?

Comment: in android works fine

Answer (score 0):

Re-adding fluttertoast work for me. All commands with pod didn't work.

```
flutter pod remove fluttertoast
flutter pod add fluttertoast
```